# Domain configuration with iis hosted website in azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine with a Website hosted on it. also by default, I have configured with azure provided DNS. but I want to configure different domain then how to configure it.

The other question is that I can publish my website to the Azure virtual machine directly but in that, I am able to publish in port 80 only, Cant I publish on other ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure DNS to host your own domain to Azure, then [create a record for the VM public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/tutorial-alias-pip). Finally, you can access your own domain to the Azure VM.

All the ports of the VM you can use for your application, not only the 80 port. But you need to allow the port which you want to use in the Azure Network Security Groups rules, also the VM firewall. You can take a look at the [Azure Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview).

If you have any more questions, please let me know, and if it's helpful, you can accept it as the answer :-)